# How to make circle bounce from diferent sides of rectangle?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, bounce

Guys i`m making an app and i have a moving circle which has to bounce of the non-movable rectangle. I already have algorithm that recognizes if the circle is in the collision with rectangle. I realized that when circle collide with horizontal side of rectangle, "y" component of  its velocity should change the sign(+,-), and opposite for vertical side. My question is: How can i know which side of rectangle did circle hit so i can make bouncing angle?

Comment: This is a bit too abstract to answer. Please read [ask] and share your code.

Comment: Add a snippet of the code you have for everyone to look at and answer

Comment: You say you have some logic that computes the collision. That logic should know what side the collision happened on.